# How to prove this inequality

Tags: inequality

Let $x,y,z>0$,and such $xyz=1$,show that
$$\dfrac{1+x^2y^2}{1+x}+\dfrac{1+y^2z^2}{1+y}+\dfrac{1+z^2x^2}{1+z}\ge 3$$

I tried using $AM-GM$ inequality, but i'm not sure how it would work ,Thanks in advance.

$$\sum\dfrac{1+x^2y^2}{1+x}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\prod\dfrac{1+x^2y^2}{1+x}}$$

Comment: HINT:I think you would have noticed that there are three very similar looking terms where just x,y,z are just in alternate form so if you prove that{ 1+(x^2)(y^2)}/1+x >1 then you can easily do the same for others and then just add them!! (The three similar inequalities) which will give you 3 on RHS as required

Comment: Does that help ?? Try it if you don't get answer or are not able to prove {1+(x^2)(y^2)}/1+x >1 ask here,I will try to put  some more hints and perhaps a part of solution

Comment: I don't think all three  are each greater than 1.  If x =1 and y < 1 then that term is less than 1.  but the z = 1/y and the other terms are large.

Comment: Yes !! Sorry!! A huge blunder on my side!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me try. $$LHS \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\prod \frac{1+x^2y^2}{1+x}} \geq 3 \sqrt[3]{\prod \frac{(1+xy)^2}{2(1+x)}} = 3 \sqrt[3]{\prod \frac{(xy)^2(1+z)^2}{2(1+x)}} = 3 \sqrt[3]{\frac{(xyz)^4}{8}\prod (1+x)} = \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{(1+x)(1+y)(1+z)} \geq \frac{3}{2}\sqrt[3]{8\sqrt{xyz}} = 3.$$

Comment: Merci bien, c'est mon erreur.